# NAT simulation for P2P data transfer

Tags: simulation, p2p, data-transfer, nat

I am currently implemented a P2P data transfer application based on Libjingle, I want to do following simulations to verify the implementation:

1. Simulate different types of NATs (full cone, port restricted cone, address restricted cone, symmetric cone)
2. Simulate the network delay, packet loss.
3. Simulate large scale P2P networks. Say, I want to deploy this application to 1000 nodes to test if the concurrently data transfer is well handled.

Is there any tools to help me to build such environment easily?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward tool available to perform such type of task, though you may build such tools by utilizing the following :

*Virtual Boxes Or  Virtual Instances or Amazon VPC etc, to simulate network

*OpenvSwitch , for various network automation

For NAT :

*You may use set of IP tables rules to prepare different types of NAT Boxes

Or

*Directly buy different type of switch to test the NAT traversing.

For Network Delay /Packet Loss:

No concrete idea as of now.